# DungeonDefenders does not start on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit

Tags: games, architecture

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 64bit with Gnome3 and the fglrx-updates graphics drivers.
The drivers work good, i.e. with Grimrock(wine), OilRush or Rochard.
Now, I bought the HumbleIndieBundle7 and want to play DungeonDefenders. I extracted the archive and found a ./DungeonDefenders script in this folder. When I start this script, the spash screen of the game appears, lasts some seconds and disappears again. Then the Program has ended. Via Terminal I can see the following output:

```
chocobai@pfubuntu:~/Arbeitsfläche/DungeonDefenders$ ./DungeonDefenders
Dungeon Defenders: Installed in '/home/chocobai/Arbeitsfläche/DungeonDefenders'.
*** glibc detected *** ./DungeonDefenders-x86: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0a9e9118 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xf7224ee2]
/home/chocobai/Arbeitsfläche/DungeonDefenders/UDKGame/Binaries/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(+0xb8072)[0xf7590072]
/home/chocobai/Arbeitsfläche/DungeonDefenders/UDKGame/Binaries/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(SDL_VideoQuit+0x6e)[0xf756f2de]
/home/chocobai/Arbeitsfläche/DungeonDefenders/UDKGame/Binaries/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(SDL_QuitSubSystem+0x16d)[0xf74e1f3d]
/home/chocobai/Arbeitsfläche/DungeonDefenders/UDKGame/Binaries/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(SDL_Quit+0x28)[0xf74e2018]
./DungeonDefenders-x86[0x9aff07b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x32f51)[0xf71e1f51]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0a4b5000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 37486660                           /home/chocobai/Arbeitsfläche/DungeonDefenders/UDKGame/Binaries/DungeonDefenders-x86
0a4b5000-0a4b6000 r-xp 0246c000 08:03 37486660                           /home/chocobai/Arbeitsfläche/DungeonDefenders/UDKGame/Binaries/DungeonDefenders-x86
0a4b6000-0a502000 rwxp 0246d000 08:03 37486660                           /home/chocobai/Arbeitsfläche/DungeonDefenders/UDKGame/Binaries/DungeonDefenders-x86
0a502000-0a5e2000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
0a9be000-0ba5b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
f0b56000-f0d56000 rwxs ef586000 00:05 9778                               /dev/ati/card0
f1100000-f11b2000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f11b2000-f1200000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
f1300000-f13ab000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f13ab000-f1400000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
f14c1000-f14c2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
f14c2000-f1cc2000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f1cc2000-f1cc3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
f1cc3000-f24c3000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f2600000-f2621000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f2621000-f2700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
f27ff000-f2800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
f2800000-f3000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:20940]
f3000000-f3021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f3021000-f3100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
f3129000-f3169000 rwxs 00027000 00:05 9778                               /dev/ati/card0
f3169000-f316a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
f316a000-f396a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:20936]
f396a000-f396b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
f396b000-f416b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:20935]
f419f000-f41a0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f41a0000-f41a7000 r-xs 00000000 08:01 1312550                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
f41a7000-f48a7000 rwxs 00006000 00:05 9778                               /dev/ati/card0
f48a7000-f4b27000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f4b27000-f4b75000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 417564                             /usr/lib32/fglrx/libatiadlxx.so
f4b75000-f4b77000 rwxp 0004e000 08:01 417564                             /usr/lib32/fglrx/libatiadlxx.so
f4b77000-f4b87000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f4bac000-f6dbb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 417567                             /usr/lib32/fglrx/dri/fglrx_dri.so
f6dbb000-f6ed0000 rwxp 0220e000 08:01 417567                             /usr/lib32/fglrx/dri/fglrx_dri.so
f6ed0000-f6f9b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f6f9b000-f6f9f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1313273                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
f6f9f000-f6fa0000 r-xp 00003000 08:01 1313273                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
f6fa0000-f6fa1000 rwxp 00004000 08:01 1313273                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
f6fa1000-f6fa3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1313796                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1.0.0
f6fa3000-f6fa4000 r-xp 00001000 08:01 1313796                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1.0.0
f6fa4000-f6fa5000 rwxp 00002000 08:01 1313796                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1.0.0
f6fa5000-f6fae000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1313187                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
f6fae000-f6faf000 r-xp 00008000 08:01 1313187                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
f6faf000-f6fb0000 rwxp 00009000 08:01 1313187                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
f6fb0000-f6fb2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1313185                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
f6fb2000-f6fb3000 r-xp 00001000 08:01 1313185                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
f6fb3000-f6fb4000 rwxp 00002000 08:01 1313185                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
f6fb4000-f6fb9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1312921                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
f6fb9000-f6fba000 r-xp 00004000 08:01 1312921                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
f6fba000-f6fbb000 rwxp 00005000 08:01 1312921                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
f6fbb000-f6fc3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1312775                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
f6fc3000-f6fc4000 r-xp 00007000 08:01 1312775                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
f6fc4000-f6fc5000 rwxp 00008000 08:01 1312775                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
f6fc5000-f6fce000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1313181                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
f6fce000-f6fcf000 r-xp 00008000 08:01 1313181                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
f6fcf000-f6fd0000 rwxp 00009000 08:01 1313181                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
f6fd0000-f7014000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f7014000-f7019000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1312733                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
f7019000-f701a000 r-xp 00004000 08:01 1312733                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
f701a000-f701b000 rwxp 00005000 08:01 1312733                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
f701b000-f701d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1312731                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
f701d000-f701e000 r-xp 00001000 08:01 1312731                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
f701e000-f701f000 rwxp 00002000 08:01 1312731                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
f701f000-f703f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1312735                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
f703f000-f7040000 r-xp 0001f000 08:01 1312735                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
f7040000-f7041000 rwxp 00020000 08:01 1312735                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
f7041000-f7173000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1312737                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0Abgebrochen
chocobai@pfubuntu:~/Arbeitsfläche/DungeonDefenders$
```

I can see that the script is executing a binary file in this folder wit x86 in the name. I wonder whether the game is not compatible with 64bit systems? It looks like it tries to execute binarys for other architectures. Is this even a problem I can solve or should I contact the Humble Support? Or am I doing something wrong? The Scrips looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# this script is for Linux!

FindPath()
{
    X=`which "$1"`
    Y=`readlink -e "$X"`
    dirname "$Y"
}

if [ "${DUNDEF_DATA_PATH}" = "" ]; then
    DUNDEF_DATA_PATH="`FindPath "$0"`"
fi

echo "Dungeon Defenders: Installed in '$DUNDEF_DATA_PATH'."
cd "$DUNDEF_DATA_PATH/UDKGame/Binaries"

exec ./DungeonDefenders-x86 "$@"
```

I can't imagine that this game only runs on 32bit and they did not tell the customers about it. Thanks for advices.

PS: Besides the x86 binary there is no alternative in this folder:

```
chocobai@pfubuntu:~/Arbeitsfläche/DungeonDefenders/UDKGame/Binaries$ ls
DungeonDefenders-x86  libopenal.so.1  libSDL2-2.0.so.0  xdg-open
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it yesterday again, and it still did not work, until I tried to save the game directly in the users folder. It works now, but not in fullscreen mode and not online.
The name of the games folder seems to be irrelevant, so you can hide it and create a desktop file to start it.